# Xamarin navigation not changing view the first time its run

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm building a Xamarin.Forms PCL application.

I have some Login logic to hande.. login..

Basically: if authtoken is present, it will call DoLogin() directly and redirect to my MasterDetail page.

Code:

```
 // tries to get remote token and calls DoLogin(Token)
   private async void AttemptLogin(string username, string password)
   {
      Debug.WriteLine("AttemptLogin");
      var service = new WebService();
      var loginTask  = service.AuthorizeCredentials(username, password);
      var token = await loginTask;
      if (token.Length > 0)
      {
        DoLogin(token);
      }
    }


    // Tries to get local token and calls DoLogin(Token)
    private void TryGetLocalAuthtoken()
    {
      if (Application.Current.Properties.ContainsKey("authToken"))
      {
        var authToken = Application.Current.Properties["authToken"].ToString();
        DoLogin(authToken);
      }
    }

  private void DoLogin(string token = null)
  {
    Application.Current.Properties["authToken"] = token; //todo add timestamp
    Debug.WriteLine("DoLogin - Token: {0}", token);
    Application.Current.MainPage = new CustomerMdPage();      
  }
```

All this code is being run, its starts my MasterDetail page and fetches data (from method in constructor)

But the page is not being redirected to the MasterDetail page, it stays on the login page.

I can then enter credentials and login, which will redirect me to my MasterDetail.

Question:

Why am I not being redirected to my MasterDetail the first time the code is run?

I'll happily post more code or clarify if this was not sufficient.

Edit: MasterDetail code was requested

```
public CustomerMdPage()
{
  _service = new WebService();
  _locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;
  _locator.DesiredAccuracy = 50;
  _dataAccess = new DataAccess();
  var listview = new ListView { ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(CustomerViewCell)) };

  listview.ItemSelected += (s, e) =>
  {
    if (e.SelectedItem != null)
    {
      Detail.BindingContext = e.SelectedItem;
      IsPresented = false;
      listview.SelectedItem = null;
    }
  };

  Master = new ContentPage()
  {
    Padding = new Thickness(20, Device.OnPlatform(40, 20, 0), 10, 20),
    Title = "Customers",
    Content = listview
  };

  GetCustomers(listview);

  Detail = new CustomerDetailPage();
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it is hitting DoLogin? Did you try setting a breakpoint? If so, can you post you CustomerMdPage Code

Comment: I am very sure, it is the sole reason this question exists. I don't see how my MasterDetail code is relevant - but sure

Comment: Hmm, the first time the breakpoint is hit, Current.MainPage is null, the second time it is = LoginView, can that be causing this maby?

Comment: yup looks like that is the cause. Try doing something simple like going to just masterdetail page on page load and see if it works, if it does that means there is something wrong with the logic

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

Inside your App.cs you can choose the MainPage of your application, for example:

```
private bool TryGetLocalAuthtoken()
{
    //maybe you can retrieve this with a setting or from the local database.
    return Application.Current.Properties.ContainsKey("authToken"));
}


NavigationPage navigationPage = null;
if (TryGetLocalAuthtoken())
{
    navigationPage = new NavigationPage(new LoginPage());
}
else 
{
    navigationPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage(StaticData.Zero));
}
AppNavigation = navigationPage.Navigation;
MainPage = navigationPage;
```

Comment: This will give me a navigation page with a back arrow to the login page right? that is what i tried to avoid. Logging out of an application is very rare in this app, and most other apps i guess..

Comment: You can get rid of the NavigationPage and do only: `MainPage = new MasterDetailPage();`

Comment: Here is an example of a MasterDetailPage using Xamarin.Forms
https://github.com/15mgm15/XamarinForms-MasterDetailPage-Recipe